# iPhone programming use one class properties in different view controllers

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

In my iphone application, I have multiple view classes and model class and I take the property  of view class to my model class via setter but I do not use in other view class this instance via getter. For instance, in viewA class I have text Field instance and in modelA class I have Nsstring object to hold textField instance, and I use the instance of ModelA in viewA and I take the textField instance to ModelA class via Setter, but in ViewB class I have instance of ModelA but I do not take this object via getter, How can I handle this problem?

p.s.I started to programming a little time ago, I am new in objective c programming..

Answer (score 0):

Its really hard to understand the specifics of your question, perhaps an example will be useful here. However, if your purpose is to share data between views you create a Data Model class in code before the views are created (maybe in the app delegate) and pass it to both view classes on creation. They can both hold a reference to the same object.

Here is a simple tutorial I wrote a while back which shows the use of multiple views in a tab bar. It passes the text from one view to the other. There is source code in the tutorial as well. The code design is not the best I have ever made but I was trying to keep it simple.

[iPhone Tab Bar tutorial](http://www.techtraits.com/iphone-sdk-tabbars/)